# pressing debugging button in Qt creator gives unknown error

Tags: android, c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I have just started internship in a company, they said i will be working on a android project using qt.I need to join them by next week, in meantime i thought of installing qt on my laptop which has Ubuntu 15.04(64-bit).
I downloaded Android SDK, Android NDK, Ant Executeable.

Here is my android settings in qt.
[image]

I created a sample app using **New Project -> Qt quick Application**,it pasted some sample code for hello world when i tried running it it said

**could not find the executable please specify one qt**

then i opened my project folder and specified a file having name same as my project name,fortunately it worked.
Now when i run the project it displays hello world but when i try to debug it either by attaching external device or through emulator it displays a pop-up which displays a string "Unknown error".

1.Have i specified the settings correctly?

2.how to get rid of this error and start debugging.

3. can i do debugging on my device in ubuntu.

I am just a beginner plz provide easily understandable answer.

Comment: `1.Have i specified the settings correctly?` - Obviously - not. If you will look your own image you'll see that `Qt versions for architectures arm, x86, mips are missing`. Looks like you ask without trying to solve this problem by yourself.

Comment: you need to setup `QT` compiler, debugger and `qmake` path in the `Build & Run` tab